# How to update weights in Stochastic Weight Averaging (SWA) on tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm confused about how to implement tfa's [SWA optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/SWA).  There are two points here:

1. When you look at the documentation it points you to [this] model averaging tutorial.  That tutorial uses tfa.callbacks.AverageModelCheckpoint, which allows you to

- Assign the moving average weights to the model, and save them.
- (or) Keep the old non-averaged weights, but the saved model uses the average weights.

Having a distinct ModelCheckpoint that allows you to save moving average weights (rather than the current weights) makes sense.  However - it seems like SWA should be managing the weight averaging.  That makes me want to set `update_weights=False`.

Is this correct?  The tutorial uses `update_weights=True`.

2. There is a note about SWA not updating the BN layers in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/SWA).  Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64376062/607528) I did this,

```py
# original training
model.fit(...)
# updating weights from final run 
optimizer.assign_average_vars(model.variables)
# batch-norm-hack: lr=0 as suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/64376062/607528
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0),
    loss=loss,
    metrics=metrics)
model.fit(
    data,
    validation_data=None,
    epochs=1,
    callbacks=final_callbacks)
```

before saving my model.

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to deal with the batch norm is the following:
First, loop through all layers in your model and reset the moving mean and moving variance in the batch norm layers (in my example I assume the batch norm layers end with "bn"):

```
for l in model.layers:
    if l.name.split('_')[-1] == 'bn': # e.g. conv1_bn
       l.moving_mean.assign(tf.zeros_like(l.moving_mean))
       l.moving_variance.assign(tf.ones_like(l.moving_variance))
```

After that run your model for one epoch and set training to true to update the moving average and variance:

```
count = 0
for x,_ in dataset_train:
    _ = model(x, training = True)
    count += 1
    if count > steps_per_epoch:
       break
```

Answer (score 1):

There are **two ways** of doing this, the first one is you **manually update the weights** before saving, like this [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/AveragedOptimizerWrapper#example_7) from the documentation.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

model = tf.Sequential([...])
opt = tfa.optimizers.SWA(
        tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=2.0), 100, 10)
model.compile(opt, ...)
model.fit(x, y, ...)

# Update the weights to their mean before saving
opt.assign_average_vars(model.variables)

model.save('model.h5')
```

The second option is to **update the weight through** `AverageModelCheckpoint` if you set `update_weights = True`. As the collab notebook [example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/addons/blob/master/docs/tutorials/average_optimizers_callback.ipynb) shows

```
avg_callback = tfa.callbacks.AverageModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_dir, 
                                                    update_weights=True)
...

#Build Model
model = create_model(moving_avg_sgd)

#Train the network
model.fit(fmnist_train_ds, epochs=5, callbacks=[avg_callback])
```

Notice that `AverageModelCheckpoint` also calls `assign_average_vars` before saving the model, from [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.12.0/tensorflow_addons/callbacks/average_model_checkpoint.py#L81):

```
def _save_model(self, epoch, logs):
    optimizer = self._get_optimizer()
    assert isinstance(optimizer, AveragedOptimizerWrapper)

    if self.update_weights:
        optimizer.assign_average_vars(self.model.variables)
        return super()._save_model(epoch, logs)
    ...
```

Comment: thanks! but I'm confused.  Note in my question I do both of your suggestions.  The opt.assign_average_vars(model.variables) updates the weights and the callback does the same but throughout training. 

To clarify my question: (1) during training should I have `update_weights=True` or is that managed by the SWA optimizer?  (2)  I don't think the `assign_average_vars`   takes care of the batch-norm weights not using the updated-weights after averaging (see note in documentation) and I wanted to know if my lr=0 fit was the correct fix

Comment: That said this made me realized that maybe `AverageModelCheckpoint` isn't handling batch-norm layers correctly ?

Comment: From the implementation of @Simon Larsson, on the [last epoch](https://github.com/simon-larsson/keras-swa/blob/master/swa/tfkeras.py#L94) updates the learning rate to [zero](https://github.com/simon-larsson/keras-swa/blob/master/swa/tfkeras.py#L159), the model weights to [swa](https://github.com/simon-larsson/keras-swa/blob/master/swa/tfkeras.py#L203) and [reset batch norm](https://github.com/simon-larsson/keras-swa/blob/master/swa/tfkeras.py#L228) before running the final epoch. When training ends it also restores the batch norm

Comment: Following that guidelines, it appears your implementation only misses restoring the batch norm before running the final train step. I would suggest you to try the [Keras SWA](https://github.com/simon-larsson/keras-swa) of Simon Larsson.

Comment: thanks miguel - somehow my questions are being missed though  - my implementation does do that: `model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0),loss=loss,metrics=metrics)
model.fit(data,validation_data=None,epochs=1,...)`